# Concatenate some columns in Panda Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to figure out how to do this. I have a text file that has data in it, such as the example below. When I read in the file using read_csv, I am left with columns of strings. I am trying to concatenate columns of each row into one column.

There will be more data in other columns that I can't concatenate, so my thinking was that with the for loop, I can change it to not loop through those columns.

.txt file:

```
Test data 1 1
Test data 2 2 2
Test data 3 3 3 3
Test data
```

My previous method was to find the lastcol and use that as the maximum, then use a for loop.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+', header=None)
cols = list(df.columns)
lastcol = cols[-1]
n = 0
df['testColumn'] = df[n].map(str)
for n in range (0,lastcol):
   df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
   df['testColumn'] = df['testColumn'] + ' ' + df[n+1].map(str)
```

This works fine when the data in row 1 has the most columns. However, this fails upon entering the second row if the data row 2 has more columns than the row 1, such as in the .txt file example.

I am thinking my issue now is in how I am grabbing the end column. I am somewhat new to Python.

Here is the current output of when a text file has the first row with the most columns:

```
      0     1  2  3  4            testColumn
0  Test  data  1  1  1  Test data 1 1.0 1.0
1  Test  data  2  2        Test data 2 2.0 
2  Test  data  3              Test data 3
```

Here is the current output error when a text file has the most columns in a different row (using text file example above):

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 2, saw 5
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to do, can you provide the output? What about `df.fillna('').apply(''.join, axis=0)` (depending on the output you want try `axis=1`)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you [edit] to include your expected output so that we can better understand how to help?

Comment: @G.Anderson Will do! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```python
import pandas as pd
import re

with open(filename) as f:
   df = pd.DataFrame([re.split(r'\s+', l.strip()) for l in f.readlines()])
df.fillna("", inplace=True)

df['testColumn'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)

print(df)

# output as a new CSV file
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=None, sep=',')
```

The first part handles the variable columns in the data and creates a data frame from a list.

If want to select which columns to concatenate try this:

```
df['testColumn'] = df[[0,2]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
      0     1  2  3  4  5         testColumn
0  Test  data  1  1          Test data 1 1
1  Test  data  2  2  2      Test data 2 2 2
2  Test  data  3  3  3  3  Test data 3 3 3 3
3  Test  data                  Test data
```

Comment: This works well. I do have a question. With this methodology (and changes made), would it be possible to concatenate select columns?

Comment: If want only columns 1 and 3 use `df['testColumn'] = df[[0,2]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be as one column, there is no need to split it in the first place:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
```

Comment: I should have clarified that I can't do this. The .txt file only part of the data I am reading, where there will be more columns that can not be concatenated that I am testing on.